# Converting timestamp returns the wrong date - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code

```
val today = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)
val dueDay = Calendar.getInstance()
dueDay.timeInMillis = 1708395041
val dueDate = dueDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)
val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
val fullDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
Log.d("t","date ${fullDateFormat.format(Date(1708395041)))
```

Why in logs I see Jan 20, 01:14 PM

But if i go this website https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ the actual date is Tue Feb 20 2024 02:10:41

Comment: `1708395041` is seconds, use `1708395041000` for milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun timeStampToReadableDate(timestamp: Long): String {
    val date = Date(timestamp * 1000)
    val df = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
    df.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()

    return df.format(date)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a year in there

```kotlin
val fullDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy, hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
```

and you will see

```
date Jan 20 1970, 11:33 AM
```

The web site you were comparing to was taking the epoch time in seconds, but the Java `Date` expects the value in milliseconds. 1708395041 milliseconds is only about 19.8 days after epoch start (putting you at Jan 20, 1970). Change that to 1708395041000 and you will see Feb 20, 2024 (depending on your locale time zone...).